# Direitos autorais e crack

Tags: licença, cracker

Que crackear um software é ilegal, todos já sabem. Mas gostaria de saber o seguinte:

É ilegal usar/distribuir/criar um produto crackeado antigo? Um que nem sequer é mais vendido pela produtora?

Por não está mais à venda, a única forma de obter sua versão pro seria usando um crack. Seria ilegal usar/distribuir/criar uma versão crackeada deste software?

Se pudessem passar links sobre direitos autorais indicando ser ilegal ou não, eu agradeceria.

Comment: É ilegal sim. Pois você infligiria o contrato de licença de uso do programa. [Este artigo - Problemas de distribuição ilegal de software via Internet](http://www.egov.ufsc.br/portal/sites/default/files/anexos/20647-20648-1-PB.htm) aborda esse assunto.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Os direitos autorais se tornam públicos depois de *70* anos segundo a Lei *[9.610](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/L9610.htm), de 19 de fevereiro de 1998*, artigo *41*, mas **não** expiram.

> A figura do direito autoral, perante ao INPI (para *software*), perante
> a Biblioteca Nacional (para literatura) e perante a Escola de Música
> tem lá um tempo burocrático razoável. Varia de *um* a *três* meses.
>
> Mas
> ele não tem tempo de expiração. O registro não expira. O que perde a
> validade é o direito ao exclusivo patrimonial sobre aquela obra depois
> de um determinado período de tempo, que hoje corresponde a *70* anos,
> contados de janeiro do ano seguinte da morte do autor.

Ou seja, sim, ainda constituiria crime, você *crackear* a obra, mesmo que ela não esteja mais sendo comercializada.

[Software: direito autoral ou propriedade industrial?](http://www.egov.ufsc.br/portal/conteudo/software-direito-autoral-ou-propriedade-industrial)

Comment: Então seria 70 anos após a morte do autor? Certo? E se a obra estiver em nome de uma empresa? Seria 70 anos após o seu fechamento legal?

Comment: @Fernando exatamente, 70 anos após a extinção total da empresa, mas lembre-se, caso não saiba, que a falência não quer dizer extinção da empresa, ela continua existindo o que juridicamente é chamado de massa falida, por mas alguns séculos, até que ela não deva mais nada ao Governo ou a sociedade e que se extingam prazos legais para cobrança de todas as dividas existentes em qualquer esfera publica ou privada...Simplificando, só daqui 1000 anos para usar este software sem pagar!

Comment: Então não existe meio legal de se obter uma cópia do produto?

Comment: @Superbomber existe sim, porém é burocratico, entrando em contato com a o sindico da massa falida (pessoa responsável pelos documentos da empresa falida, geralmente um dos sócios) e solicitando que ele redija e reconheça em cartório a cessão dos direitos ou propriedade intelectual da obra, o que não é usual e nem comum, além de ser muito difícil você conseguir encontrar o sindico da massa falida.

Answer (score 6):

A resposta aceita tem algumas falhas. Não mudam a conclusão, mas está errada em alguns pontos.

A Lei dos Direitos Autorais ([9.610/98](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/L9610.htm)) realmente se aplica **em parte** aos "programas de computador", mas é na Lei [9.609/98](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l9609.htm) que está a maior parte da fundamentação da sua resposta.

Em primeiro lugar, os direitos do autor de um "programa de computador" caem em domínio público no prazo de **50 anos**, nos termos do parágrafo 2º do art. 2º:

> § 2º Fica assegurada a tutela dos direitos relativos a programa de
> computador pelo prazo de **cinqüenta anos**, contados a partir de 1º de
> janeiro do ano subseqüente ao da sua publicação ou, na ausência desta,
> da sua criação.

Eu cheguei até a ficar em dúvida se a resposta não poderia ser **Não** para o simples **uso**, porque a lei brasileira é bastante permissiva, e de todos os direitos morais do autor, previstos no art. 24 da Lei 9.610/98 (vide o [art. 24](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/L9610.htm)), apenas dois foram assegurados pela Lei 9.609/98:

> § 1º Não se aplicam ao programa de computador as disposições relativas
> aos direitos morais, ressalvado, a qualquer tempo, **o direito do
> autor de reivindicar a paternidade** do programa de computador **e o
> direito do autor de opor-se a alterações não-autorizadas, quando estas
> impliquem deformação, mutilação ou outra modificação do programa de
> computador, que prejudiquem a sua honra ou a sua reputação**.

O problema é que você agrediria os direitos **patrimoniais** do autor, dentre os quais estão:

> Art. 29. Depende de autorização prévia e expressa do autor a utilização da obra, por quaisquer modalidades, tais como:
>
> I - a reprodução parcial ou integral; 
> II - a edição; [...] 
> VI - a distribuição, quando não intrínseca ao contrato firmado pelo autor com
> terceiros para uso ou exploração da obra;

Então, ao `crackear` e distribuir o programa, você incidiria no art. 12 da Lei 9.609/98:

> Art. 12. **Violar direitos de autor de programa de computador:**
>
> Pena - Detenção de **seis meses a dois anos** ou multa.

E se for para fins de comércio é bem pior:

> § 1º Se a violação consistir na reprodução, por qualquer meio, de
> programa de computador, no todo ou em parte, **para fins de comércio**,
> sem autorização expressa do autor ou de quem o represente:
>
> Pena - Reclusão de **um a quatro anos** e multa.
>
> § 2º Na mesma pena do parágrafo anterior incorre quem vende, expõe à
> venda, introduz no País, adquire, oculta ou tem em depósito, para fins
> de comércio, original ou cópia de programa de computador, produzido
> com violação de direito autoral.